# ASCII codes for Ctrl-Up and Ctrl-Down

Tags: c, terminal, ascii

I'm implementing a small shell in C and I want to use `Ctrl-Up` and `Ctrl-Down`. Are there ASCII codes for `Ctrl-Up`, `Ctrl-Down` and `Ctrl-Shift+C`? I have searched everywhere for them and I couldn't find them.

Comment: By "C-Up," etc., do you mean "Ctrl-Up," etc.?

Comment: Just look at a [table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @EdCottrell Yes `C` for `CTRL`

Comment: @George I have already done that and I think there are not there.

Comment: There are no direct ASCII codes for those direct inputs. However, in the extended ASCII set, there are `0x5C` and `0x60` which correspond for left and right ctrl respectively.

Comment: @MateoConLechuga to get `Ctrl+Up` I need to combine those values?

Comment: Each keypress sequence produces a unique *'scancode'*. For `ctrl+up` the hex scancode is `1b 5b 31 3b 35 41` for `ctrl+down` it is `... 42`. You can write a fairly simple handler to test for the code, but you are better served using a predefined library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MateoConLechuga mentioned, what you're looking for simply doesn't exist. What actually happens when you press `Ctrl-Up` is that the terminal sends a [special sequence of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) starting with the `ESC` character. For example, on my terminal, `Ctrl-Up` sends `ESC[1;5A`.

What you need to to is use something like the [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) and/or the [termcap](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html) libraries to deal with things like terminal input in a terminal-independent manner.

Unfortunately for you, this is probably way more work that you were hoping for. Writing a "small" shell is non-trivial.

Comment: I'm using `termcap` I can capture `5D` or `^[[1;5D`  and `5C` or `^[[1;5C`  which is `CTRL+LEFT` and `CTRL+RIGHT`, for some reason I can't capture  `CTRL+UP`  on my terminal

Comment: Maybe your terminal simply doesn't support `Ctrl-up`. You'll have to RTFM for whatever terminal you are using.

Comment: I tested it on my other terminal and it's working, `guake` doesn't pick up `Ctrl-up`.